# Determining system architecture

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

Does anyone know of a program or script I can use to find out what architecture my Sony VAIO PCV-RS520 desktop computer is? I've been mulling over an upgrade to 14.04 64-bit, however I am not sure if the computer can handle it.

Here is the output of `/proc/cpuinfo`. [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/PLJeacAk)

I know each core says it has 32 bits of virtual address sizes, but I am not sure if these combine or if I am limited to 32-bit operating systems.

(P.S. No, if the current setup isn't 64-bit capable, I'm not replacing anything, hardware or otherwise.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked http://ark.intel.com/products/27497/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-supporting-HT-Technology-3_00-GHz-1M-Cache-800-MHz-FSB

It's the product page for the CPU

Says 32-bit

Comment: I'll also add that P4 are single core processors, but hyper-threaded (1 core is emulated, but not present physically).

Comment: Yes, this helps. Now I'm glad I didn't try installing a 64-bit version before, when I first got the computer. (I'll accept this answer when the site lets me.)

Comment: Generally, posting a link as an answer is considered poor style. Post the info from the link and credit the source.

Answer (score 1):

Most reliable method is

```
grep ' lm ' /proc/cpuinfo
```

If you get output your cpu is 64 bit (the lm flag is the most reliable). If you do not get any output your cpu is 32 bit.

> lm: Long Mode (x86-64: amd64, also known as Intel 64, i.e. 64-bit capable)

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/what-do-the-flags-in-proc-cpuinfo-mean for additional information.

```
uname -r
```

will show your current kernel (32 bit bs 64 bit + kernel version).

Comment: Yup, I'm 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run this command

> file /sbin/init

At the output

```
/sbin/init: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, if you get like this yours is 32bit version Ubuntu


/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, if you get like this yours is 64bit version ubuntu
```

The command tells which version(whether 32bit or 64bit) of ubuntu installed in your pc, but not your cpu 32bit or 64bit.